# Merging two DataFrames on closest UNIX Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, timestamp

I have two sets of data, usually of different lengths, of which contain a UNIX time-stamp column. One dateframe usually has consistently spaced data while the off has some offset but still every 5 seconds (0,5,10,15 vs 3,8,13,18) that is not predictable.

```
               df1                            df2
0        1428796819     |      0        1428796800
1        1428796824     |      1        1428796805
2        1428796829     |      2        1428796810
3        1428796834     |      3        1428796815
4        1428796839     |      4        1428796820
5        1428796844     |      5        1428796825
```

I'm looking to merge these two Dataframes based on the closest date. I'm fine with there being 'NaN' as a result of the df lengths not matching. The UNIX timestamps are in 'int64' format.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: In the example above, many values in `df1` are closest to the same value in `df2`. For example, all the values in `df1` except the first are closest to the last value in `df2`. How do you wish to merge rows in this situation? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to resample your timestamp like this:

```
data = """\
ts
1428796819
1428796824
1428796829
1428796834
1428796839
1428796844
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), parse_dates=['ts'], date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s'))
df1['df1'] = range(len(df1))


data = """\
ts
1428796800
1428796805
1428796810
1428796815
1428796820
1428796825
"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), parse_dates=['ts'], date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s'))
df2['df2'] = range(len(df2))


(df1.set_index('ts')
    .resample('5S')
    .last()
    .join(df2.set_index('ts')
             .resample('5S')
             .last(),
          rsuffix='_r')
)
```

Test:

```
In [88]: df1
Out[88]:
                   ts  df1
0 2015-04-12 00:00:19    0
1 2015-04-12 00:00:24    1
2 2015-04-12 00:00:29    2
3 2015-04-12 00:00:34    3
4 2015-04-12 00:00:39    4
5 2015-04-12 00:00:44    5

In [89]: df2
Out[89]:
                   ts  df2
0 2015-04-12 00:00:00    0
1 2015-04-12 00:00:05    1
2 2015-04-12 00:00:10    2
3 2015-04-12 00:00:15    3
4 2015-04-12 00:00:20    4
5 2015-04-12 00:00:25    5

In [90]: (df1.set_index('ts')
   ....:     .resample('5S')
   ....:     .last()
   ....:     .join(df2.set_index('ts')
   ....:              .resample('5S')
   ....:              .last(),
   ....:           rsuffix='_r')
   ....: )
Out[90]:
                     df1  df2
ts
2015-04-12 00:00:15    0  3.0
2015-04-12 00:00:20    1  4.0
2015-04-12 00:00:25    2  5.0
2015-04-12 00:00:30    3  NaN
2015-04-12 00:00:35    4  NaN
2015-04-12 00:00:40    5  NaN
```

Comment: Apologies for the slow response. This is the closest I've been, thank you so much. I'm noticing that often the match will be off by one row. So a HH:MM:04 matches the HH:MM:00 instead of the .05. Any ideas what's going on here? Again, I can't thank you enough for getting me this far.